# glGetUniform returns -1 for active uniform

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I have this code calling glGetUniform location but it's returning -1 even though I'm using the uniform in my vertex shader. I don't get any errors from `glGetError` or `glGetProgramInfoLog` or `glGetShaderInfoLog` and the shaders/program all gets created successfully. I also only call this after it gets compiled and linked.

`int projectionUniform = glGetUniformLocation( shaderProgram, "dfProjection" );`

```
#version 410

uniform float   dfRealTime;
uniform float   dfGameTime;
uniform mat4    dfProjection;
uniform mat4    dfModelView;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 vertColor;

smooth out vec4 color;

out vec4 position;

void main() {
    color = vertColor;

    position = (dfModelView * dfProjection) * vec4(vertPosition, 1.0);
}
```

This is the fragment shader:

```
smooth in vec4 color;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main() {
    fragColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three positibilites:

- You have mis-spelled `dfProjection` in `glGetUniformLocation`, but it doesn't seem so.
- <del>You are not binding the correct program before calling `glGetUniformLocation` using `glUseProgram`.</del>
- Or you are not using `position` in your fragment shader, which means `dfProjection` is not really active.

Another thing from the code it seems you are passing the shader handle to `glGetUniformLocation` you should pass the linked *program* handle instead.

After your edit you are not using position in your fragment shader,

```
smooth in vec4 color;
out vec4 fragColor;
in vec4 position;
void main() {
    // do sth with position here
    fragColor = color*position;
}
```

Keep in mind that you still need to use `gl_Position` in-order for the fragment shader to know the final fragment position. But I was answering the question of why a uniform variable is not being detected.

Comment: I thought you could define an out vec4 in a vertex shader instead of using gl_Position? Maybe that's what I'm doing wrong. And I am passing in the program handle, I just called it shader which is probably a bad name.

Comment: Oh okay. Well then I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @TomTetlaw show us your fragment shader, and btw are you sure you are passing the program handle to `glGetUniformLocation` not the shader ?

Comment: @TomTetlaw as I said in my answer you are **not** using `position` in your fragment shader.

Comment: Oh, okay.. so how do I convert the vertPosition from model space to world space/screen space, if it just optimizes out the matricies? I didn't think I needed the position in the fragment shader at all

Comment: @TomTetlaw use gl_Position instead, I retract my first comment

Comment: @TomTetlaw you can (and should) use an out vec4 in place of gl_FragColor for fragment shaders.  For vertex shaders, if you use an out vec4 instead of gl_Position, GL has no way of knowing whether your output is meant for the fragment shader or as the position.  Hence the deprecation of gl_FragColor, but not gl_Position.

Comment: @concept3d: Your second point is wrong: `glGetUniformLocation` can query the locations of uniforms of any (successfully linked) program, not just the current one.